# Does Janna's shield increase a tower's damage?

Tags: league-of-legends

Janna's [Eye of the Storm](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Janna_the_Storm%27s_Fury#Eye_Of_The_Storm) grants bonus AD whenever it is cast on a target and you can cast it on towers. Do the turrets gain damage when they gain AD or is their shot damage independent of their AD?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it does grant the turret bonus ad

Be careful when using it when your carry is trying to last hit under the tower because it can screw them up badly

http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Janna/Ability_Details